# Cordova Custom-URL-scheme plugin not working

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, oracle-maf

The only plugin I can find is this one https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

I try to install it and check its iOS implementation, it is empty inside `plugins/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme/src/` (no `ios` folder found, only `android` and `window`). I check the `plugins/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme/www/ios/LaunchMyApp.js`, the content is:

```
"use strict";

/*
 Q: Why an empty file?
 A: iOS doesn't need plumbing to get the plugin to work, so..
    - Including no file would mean the import in index.html would differ per platform.
    - Also, using one version and adding a userAgent check for Android feels wrong.
    - And if you're not using PhoneGap Build, you could paste your handleOpenUrl JS function here.
*/
```

It doesn't make sense, based on my understanding, it should implement `func application(_application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:] ) -> Bool` in the `AppDelegate`, but it is empty. In this case, how come overwrite `handleOpenURL` in the `JS` will work?

I really couldn't find others, can anyone advise similar workable plugin? My scenario is, when A app call B app, my B app is a cordova app, and I need a listener/callback to capture the url content.

Updated:

added in `MAF` tag, as the issue was caused by Oracle MAF framework, didn't expect that, thought the issue coming from Cordova.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I know why there is no such implementation in https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

That is because in `cordova-ios` [CDVHandleOpenURL.m](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/Classes/Private/Plugins/CDVHandleOpenURL/CDVHandleOpenURL.m), it already contained such implementation, it will consume the notification which is posted by the `CDVAppDelegate.m`, and in the `CDVHandleOpenURL.m`, it will execute `handleOpenURL` in the WebView JavaScript namespace.

The reason why my apps is not working, it is because Cordova was wrapped in the Oracle MAF framework, and it overwrite the custom URL mechanism provided by Cordova, which is not what I expected, so I forgot to mention MAF in my original question, I will add in related information.

reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf210/mobile/develop-maf/maf-ui-remote-url.htm#ADFMF24147

Answer (score 0):

It should not implement something in iOS. Custom URL scheme only updates `Info.plist` in iOS. So, it's fine. It REGISTERS custom URL schemes.

To handle the URL them you need to right your own code. How plugin will know what you need when custom URL is opened?